# Tableview style cell dependent on a value in a dictionary

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying desperately to figure out how i can go about setting a Tableview style cell dependent on a value in a dictionary.
The dictionary is a SQLite row, and i've set a column up to set which cell to use (The Type column) This should then tell cellForRowAtIndexPath which cell style to use.
In my mind this code should work no problems, but i keep getting the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource
>   must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'

Any help would be great!
many thanks,
Andrew

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
dictionary = [tableDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    if ([dictionary objectForKey:@"Type"] == @"1") {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0];
        cell.detailTextLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0];
    }
    else if ([dictionary objectForKey:@"Type"] == @"0") {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0];
    }

}
// Configure the cell...
cell.textLabel.text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Title"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Right_Info"];
return cell; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to compare two `NSString` objects you should use the `isEqualToString:` method. With the `==` operator you are comparing the two pointers.

Also, `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` already returns an instance of `UITableViewCell` so you should not try to alloc one again.

If you like, take a look at the [Table View Programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html). It won't hurt.